# How do I remove the Sense HAT GPIO connector thats stuck to my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

A while ago, I had attached a Sense Hat onto my Raspberry Pie 3B+ for a certain project. Once I was finished, I left it for a long time.

I decided to start using it again and upon removing the Sense hat screws and the board itself, the GPIO extender seems to be effectively stuck onto my pi. I have used a great amount of force to try and pull this off (I tried my best to not damage or bend any pins) but to no avail.

What next?
[image: My raspberry pi and its sense hat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to pull it off. You have to wiggle with a tad bit of force. At first, it usually looks as if you're making no progress, but it is coming off slowly, so don't lose hope!

Comment: You can usually insert a flat screwdriver blade and slowly lever the connector apart, alternating between each end.